# jQuery height() of div incorrect on orientation change

Tags: jquery, mobile, resize, height, orientation-changes

I want to change some div element heights based on the size of the resized elements inside those divs after the orientation of the user's device changes.  Basically its a responsive list of images and article titles.  The heights are correct when the page first loads, but the heights that I grabbing on the orientation changes are incorrect.  I've been struggling with this for the past day.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

html

```
<div id="mn_category_list_container">
<div class="mn_category_post mn_post_1" style="height: 283px;">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="ui-link" data-ajax="false">
            <img class="mn_img" src="http://baconmockup.com//144/128">
            <h2>Title 1</h2>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
<div class="mn_category_post mn_post_2 right_post" style="height: 283px;">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="ui-link" data-ajax="false">
            <img class="mn_img" src="http://baconmockup.com//144/128">
            <h2>Title 2</h2>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
<div class="mn_category_post mn_post_3" style="height: 283px;">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="ui-link" data-ajax="false">
            <img class="mn_img" src="http://baconmockup.com//144/128">
            <h2>Title 3</h2>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
<div class="mn_category_post mn_post_4 right_post" style="height: 283px;">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="ui-link" data-ajax="false">
            <img class="mn_img" src="http://baconmockup.com//144/128">
            <h2>Title 4</h2>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

scss

```
#mn_category_list_container {
  @include cf;
  .mn_category_post {
    float:left;
    width: 48%;
    margin-bottom: 23px;
    li {
      list-style-type: none;
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        img {
          margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .right_post {
    float: right;
    width: 48%;
  }
}
```

js (note Im using jQuery mobile, I had to disable some of there stuff like the ajax links that I wasnt using so I put it in the code here, not too relevant)

```
var MN = MN || {}; 

(function($) {

// MOBILE SPECIFIC FUNCTIONS
MN.MOBILE = {

    // Assigns heights to lis so rows (2 posts per) are even heights
    catPostHeighterer: function() {
        elementHeights = $('.mn_category_post li').map(function() {
            return $(this).outerHeight();
        }).get();

        maxHeight_row1 = Math.max(elementHeights.slice(0,1), elementHeights.slice(1,2));
        maxHeight_row2 = Math.max(elementHeights.slice(2,3), elementHeights.slice(3,4));

        $('.mn_post_1, .mn_post_2').css('height', maxHeight_row1);
        $('.mn_post_3, .mn_post_4').css('height', maxHeight_row2);
    },

    imageResizerer: function() {
        viewport = updateViewportDimensions();
        img_width = $('.mn_category_post').width(); // width based on the width of is css class, which is defined in code as % of window width
        img_height = Math.round(img_width * .89);  // ratio of width to height based on designs
        $(".mn_img").attr('src', "http://baconmockup.com//" + img_width + "/" + img_height);
    },

    init: function() {

        MN.MOBILE.imageResizerer();
        $(window).load(function() {
            MN.MOBILE.catPostHeighterer();
        });

        $(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
            MN.MOBILE.imageResizerer();
            MN.MOBILE.catPostHeighterer();
        });

        // disable jQuery Mobile's ajax stuff
        $('a').attr('data-ajax','false');

        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
            //apply overrides here
            $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
        });
    }
}

})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    if (viewport.width <= 783) {

        MN.MOBILE.init();

    }

});
```

Things I've tried already - using outerHeight() instead of height() in my js, setting timeouts on the image resizing and category height resizing.  Grabing the containing divs of the list items (mn_category_post) and sizing those.  Using resize instead of orientationchange.  Not using jquery at all.  I am out of ideas.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, I guess my question is just too hard for the internet.  I ended up just writing a function that would calculate all the values that I needed on window load, for both portrait and landscape mode.  Then on orientation change i would just grab those values instead of recalculating them on a changing DOM.  What do I get for answering my own question?

--edit--
also, I had to change the onorientationchange to resize.  Not sure why it works now.  If you want to see my new code, please post and I will post it.